# How to count all rows and return 0 for those that no exist in result set

Tags: mysql

I' ve got this MySQL schema [Mysql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec7c4/1).

```
GRPS                        GRP_USRS
grpID | name                usrID | grpID  
------------                --------------
1     | A                   1     | 1
2     | B                   2     | 1
3     | C                   3     | 1
4     | D                   4     | 1
5     | E                   16    | 2
                            11    | 3
                            12    | 3
```

My goal is to fetch all groups with total users count,  including 0. 
Something like this:

```
grpID | count(*)
--------------
1     | 4
2     | 1
3     | 2
4     | 0
5     | 0
```

I tried:

```
SELECT grps.grpID, IFNULL(COUNT(grp_usrs.usrID), 0) AS users
FROM grps 
     INNER JOIN grp_usrs ON grps.grpID = grp_usrs.grpID
GROUP BY grps.grpID ASC;
```

but it resulted in:

```
grpID | count(*)
--------------
1     | 4
2     | 1
3     | 2
```

How do I include them whose count is 0

Comment: Nice that you provided a fiddle and formatted your question well.

Comment: Thanks trincot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. You should use left join:

```
SELECT grps.grpID, COUNT(grp_usrs.usrID) AS users
FROM grps 
LEFT JOIN grp_usrs ON grps.grpID = grp_usrs.grpID
GROUP BY grps.grpID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `left join`

```
SELECT grps.grpID, COUNT(grp_usrs.usrID) AS users
FROM grps 
LEFT JOIN grp_usrs ON grps.grpID = grp_usrs.grpID
GROUP BY grps.grpID ASC
```

And you don't need to check with `ifnull`. Also see [this great explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you guys.. Correct answer both !